# How to pass string and dictionary as arguments to vectorized Python UDF definition in Snowflake

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a python vectorized udf to process columns in a table. I want to pass the column to be processed and 2 additional arguments to the udf, one arguments is a string and the other is a dictionary. The processing of the column depends on these two additional arguments.

I tried to access these additional arguments via index as mentioned in the snowflake document but I got an error which suggested they cannot be access via index.
I am new to snowpark hence I could be making a silly mistake somewhere. I may have misread the doc but accessing arguments via index feels kind of odd.

Can someone help me with an example showing how to pass additional arguments to vectorized udfs ?

Note: I am creating a stored procedure like

```
create or replace function DO_DQ_TEST(col int ,dq_name string, dq_test string, params VARIANT)
.....
.....
.....
@vectorized(input=pd.DataFrame)
def do_dq_udf(df):
  dq_name  = 1
  dq_test = 2
  params = 3
  <do_something>
```

Answer (score 1):

I going to be real honest, this is bending my mind.

Here is a janky Python vector function:

```
create or replace function add_inputs(dq_test string,  params variant)
returns string
language python
runtime_version = 3.8
packages = ('pandas')
handler = 'add_inputs'
as $$
import pandas
from _snowflake import vectorized

@vectorized(input=pandas.DataFrame)
def add_inputs(df):
  k = df[0]
  d = df[1]

  return d[0][k[0]][0]
$$;
```

That return is some form of joke, if I use string as the second param, I can just return d, but once it becomes a dictionary, it needs to be the first thing, or I get a SERIES error, and then the first thing of the k needs to be used. and more SERIES errors if trying return the whole string, but the first character of the out...

So there is something "very wrong with the above"..

and with this SQL

```
with example_data as (
    select parse_json('{"one":"1", "two":"2", "three":"3.14"}') as json_object
    --select parse_json('["one","1", "two","2", "three","3.14"]') as json_object
)
select *
    --d.json_object as obj
   --,f.key::text as key
   ,add_inputs(f.key::text, d.json_object) as res
from example_data as d,
    table(flatten(input=>d.json_object)) as f
```

I get:

[image]

which is the first character of each output string. I get REALLY strange behavior, if I remove the `*` from the select and just ask for the details I want.

Comment: haha thank you ! This helps me provide a direction. This is a tricky on it seems

Comment: Would love to know how this gets solved in the end.